# How family member can access my passwords if I'm incapacitated or dead?

Tags: security, password-manager, sharing

I want to designate a certain person to be able to access my account credentials (e.g. the contents of my Bitwarden or LastPass) if and only if I'm dead or severely incapacitated (such as unresponsive in the intensive care unit of the hospital for a certain amount of time) and it's an emergency.

I think maybe a decent approach would be inspired by [Shamir's Secret Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing#Shamir%27s_scheme).

Maybe it would work like this:

I designate 1 beneficiary and 3+ other verifiers, and I choose an override time window.

If the beneficiary initiates the system (e.g. claims that I'm dead), then an announcement gets broadcast (via email, SMS, etc) to me and all the other verifiers.

If I or any verifier responds (before the override time window expires) that I'm alive, the system goes dormant again.

If at least 2 (and this number could be configurable) of the verifiers confirm that I'm incapacitated *and* nobody argues before the expiration, then the beneficiary receives all of my account credentials.

I think these would need to include URL, username, password, and 2FA backup code (in case my phone was unavailable or inaccessible).

Does any tool exist to do what I've described?

Maybe some kind of blockchain app would be helpful for what I'm envisioning.

Comment: I like this idea. Not quite the same thing but google does have an Inactive Account Manager (https://myaccount.google.com/inactive) that allows you to specify a person who will be able to download your data if your account becomes inactive for a certain amount of time (like if you die). I'm not sure if it allows them to have access to the passwords you have stored with Google, however.

Comment: @AdamPlocher Getting Google's email about that page is what prompted me to be thinking about this, actually. :-)